# Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT map control Release Handlers

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want know when map control from toolbox, release for user drag or some similar gesture.

I try all handlers DragLeave , LostFocus etc but never run.

I use following code on Map_CenterChanged event handler. My app add pushpin center on app and every time center changed add another DraggablePin where follow center position everytime.

Map.CenterChanged += Map_CenterChanged;

```
        if (Map.Children.Contains(firstpin))
            Map.Children.Remove(firstpin);

        Map.DesiredPitch = 0;

        MapControl.SetLocation(DraggablePin, CenterGeoPoint());
        MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(DraggablePin, new Point(0.5, 0.5));

        if (Map.Children.Count==0)
            Map.Children.Add(DraggablePin);
        else
            Map.UpdateLayout();
```

I want messagedialog where Map_CenterChanged stopped run.

Please help !

Comment: Try to make a minimal sample of your problem and include it here, because otherwise the questions is too open-ended.

Comment: thanks, i edit my answer