# MapItemsControl Tapped Event on WP 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 RT project and i want to get my binding item when mapcontrolSP tapped.

```
    <Maps:MapControl x:Name="Map" MapServiceToken="abcdef-abcdefghijklmno">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapitem" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="mapcontrolSP" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red" Tapped="ItemStckPanel">
                        <Image Source="Assets/ico-venue.png" Height="45" Width="45"
                           Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Geopoint}"
                           Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding Anchor}"/>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding address}"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="15" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding distance}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>
    </Maps:MapControl>
```

I create a tapped event on the StackPanel element but item is null:

```
    private void ItemStckPanel(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            var item = sender as FsqBasicItem;
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(item.name);
            dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

How can i get item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast solution:

```
private void ItemStckPanel(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
        var item = stackPanel.DataContext as FsqBasicItem;
        if(item != null)
        {
            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(item.name);
            dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
}
```

Comment: Exception again . Now stackpanel is null. I use this line for binding mapitem.ItemsSource = basicItemsList;

Comment: Hmm. Could you show me how it looks in code? Cause in my test solution, this code: http://pastebin.com/cYMVivQc is working very well.

Comment: Hmm i checked this on emulator (at this moment unfortunatelly dont have device) and it works for me. 

This is my solution: http://1drv.ms/1Kowjxf maybe you find something :)

Comment: your solution works perfect. My FsqbasicClass doesn't work good. Your class is good for me . Thanks :)

Comment: Please check out and this every time you want. I dont find solution yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652666/windows-phone-8-1-winrt-map-control-release-handlers